# converting diagonal style row to single row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some ranking table like below, and the table element looks some what like diagonal.

```
A            B           C     
------------------------------
Icecream     NULL        NULL
Waffle       NULL        NULL
Banana       NULL        NULL
NULL         Cherry      NULL
NULL         Apple       NULL
NULL         Coke        NULL
NULL         NULL        Banana
NULL         NULL        Cake
NULL         NULL        Waffle
```

And I want to convert upper table like below

```
A            B           C     
------------------------------
Icecream     Cherry      Banana
Waffle       Apple       Cake
Banana       Coke        Waffle
```

There are some examples of converting this style table to single row style table when the elements are numeric type. But it's hard to find when it is varchar style like this

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` and aggregation:

```
select max(a) as a, max(b) as b, max(c) as c
from ((select t.a, null as b, null as c, row_number() over (order by rownum) as seqnum
       from t
       where a is not null
      ) union all
      (select null, t.b, null, row_number() over (order by rownum) as seqnum
       from t
       where b is not null
      ) union all
      (select null, null, t.c, row_number() over (order by rownum) as seqnum
       from t
       where c is not null
      )
     ) abc
group by seqnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Break your table up into separate views by column, then join the views back together by ROWNUM:

```
WITH cteA AS (SELECT ROWNUM AS RN, A FROM DATA_TABLE WHERE A IS NOT NULL),
     cteB AS (SELECT ROWNUM AS RN, B FROM DATA_TABLE WHERE B IS NOT NULL),
     cteC AS (SELECT ROWNUM AS RN, C FROM DATA_TABLE WHERE C IS NOT NULL)
SELECT A, B, C
  FROM cteA
  INNER JOIN cteB USING (RN)
  INNER JOIN cteC USING (RN)
```

If you happen to have a database which doesn't support `WITH` you can do the same thing with sub-selects:

```
SELECT A, B, C
  FROM (SELECT ROWNUM AS RN, A FROM DATA_TABLE WHERE A IS NOT NULL)
  INNER JOIN (SELECT ROWNUM AS RN, B FROM DATA_TABLE WHERE B IS NOT NULL)
    USING (RN)
  INNER JOIN (SELECT ROWNUM AS RN, C FROM DATA_TABLE WHERE C IS NOT NULL)
    USING (RN)
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=dc49a6415041d6f82ad86b774fa27408)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `LEAD` analytical function with `ROWNUM` (if you have `ID` in your table which contains values for ordering the records then you can use that `ID` column instead of `ROWNUM`) as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT A, 
LEAD(B,ROWNUM) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS B,
LEAD(C,ROWNUM) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS C
FROM YOUR_TABLE)
WHERE A IS NOT NULL;
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6d16db3049e06da4810c3db1c0854d5b)

Cheers!!